# Saving a Backbone model where i've created a collection inside

Tags: design-patterns, backbone.js, collections, model

I have a model called 'Playlist' I got back from the server which has an array of objects called 'videos'.  When i fetch the 'Playlist' data from the server I need to turn 'videos' into a Collection.  I update the models in the 'videos' collection sometimes.  Now when I go to save 'Playlist' model, will there be a problem because I've set the 'videos' attribute to a Collection?  Will I need to turn it back into a raw array of items before saving it?

If anyone can give me any tips on the best pattern for this situation that would be good.  Perhaps I should create a separate collection and leave the Playlist's 'video' attribute alone and when I go to save the Playlist model I can override the Playlist's video attribute with a raw copy of the Collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ....will there be a problem because I've set the 'videos' attribute to
>   a Collection?

Yes there will. As you say, you need to serialize the collection before sending.

I think the best approach is to have a property which is a Backbone Collection, separate to your `videos` attribute. You update this collection on `initialize` and `sync`.

You will only use the `videos` property as a means to populate your collection.

My advice would be to override Backbone's `save` method in your `Playlist` model to serialize your video collection. Once you serialize your collection your hand the saving of the model back to the Backbone save method.

```
Model.Playlist = Backbone.Model.extend({

    initialize: function(options){
        this.initializeVideoCollection();

        this.on('sync', this.initializeVideoCollection, this);
    },

    initializeVideoCollection: function(){
        this.videoCollection = new Collections.VideoCollection(this.get('videos'));
    },

    save: function(attrs, options){
        attrs = attrs || this.toJSON();

        attrs.videos = this.videoCollection.toJSON();

        options.attrs = attrs;

        return Backbone.Model.prototype.save.call(this, attrs, options);
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution to this has normally been to expose the collection on an as-needed basis.  In other words, your model should create the collection only when someone explicitly needs it:

```
Model.Playlist = Backbone.Model.extend({

     getVideosCollection: function() {
         if (!this._videos) {
             this._videos = new Collections.VideoCollection(this.get('videos'));
             // If people will be making changes to the videos,
             // you can keep the local data synchronized easily.
             this.listenTo(this._videos, 'add change remove', this._updateVideos);
         }
         return this._videos;
     }

     // Method called when the externally-shared collection is
     // modified
     _updateVideos: function() {
         this.set('videos', this._videos.toJSON());
     }
});
```

That way the rest of your Backbone parsing & saving structure stays the same.